# how to fix Clockpicker (plugin for Bootstrap) twelveHours option in bootstrap modal (chrome specific)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm hoping someone can help my with this problem. I'm using ClockPicker with the "twelvehour" option set on a modal. The AM / PM buttons are not clickable at all. when attempting to click on the either one the clockPicker just vanishes.
This is specific to Google Chrome, I tried it on PC and Mac. Works fine in Firefox.

I placed an alert on the AM button to see if it gets triggered and it does not.

```
$('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default clockpicker-button am-button">'+ " AM" +'</button>')
            .on("click", function() {
                self.amOrPm = " AM"; 
                alert('Foo');
                $('.clockpicker-span-am-pm').empty().append(' AM');
            }).appendTo(this.amPmBlock);
```

outside a modal the alert fires but inside it does not. 
I also tried:
1. moving the clockpicker-span-am-pm element above the clickpicker-plate but the results were the same. 
2. adding a z-index to clickpicker-span-am-pm and to clockpicker-button also did not yield any results. 
3. making the modal big enough so that the clock picker is not outside of it.

The closest thing i found online with a similar issue was: [How to get ClockPicker for Bootstrap (Plugin) to appear in a Bootstrap Modal pop up form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960866/how-to-get-clockpicker-for-bootstrap-plugin-to-appear-in-a-bootstrap-modal-pop)

which is what my jsfiddle is based on: http://jsfiddle.net/pLh5G/10/

I can't think of what else I can try, or how Chrome is treating it different.

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of research. I decided to remove the AM PM block out of the clock picker and just use an extra button set provided by: http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Comment: I'm having the same problem and learned on GitHub that this clock picker is no longer maintained.